# How to run python in .Net?

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, python.net

When i run pythonnet in .net it comes up with these errors:

```
MissingMethodException: Failed to load symbol Py_IncRef.
Win32Exception: The specified procedure could not be found
```

I use python 3.7 and visual studio 2022

i tried changing the platform and tried some other ways like others said but it still gives the same error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you did not set `PythonDLL` property correctly, which would make Python.NET load a library, that does not have `Py_IncRef` function like `python*.dll`s do.